# Angular 9 compilation errors after migration from Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular9

I migrated my angular app from version 8 to 9.  After running ng serve --open, my app opens in the browser and gets stuck at the loading screen with this error in the console window:

```
core.js:610 Uncaught Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!
  - JIT compilation is discouraged for production use-cases! Consider AOT mode instead.
  - Did you bootstrap using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server'?
  - Alternatively provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.
    at getCompilerFacade (core.js:610)
    at Function.get (core.js:38351)
    at getNgModuleDef (core.js:2195)
    at assertNgModuleType (core.js:2933)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:41373)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:41740)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

Comment: i think so you need to run based on this command ng serve --open=true|false for check [serve](https://angular.io/cli/serve)

Comment: install "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" and serve again

Answer (score 0):

**Check in app.module.ts** if you are missing module...For example some times in module file people import HttpClient instead of **HttpClientModule** or it may be because of angular material for example people use MatButton instead of **MatButtonModule** sometimes which leads to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be following command would work:

```
npm update
```

Or, you could try deleting `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and then executing the following command:

```
npm install
```